# Basic Bootstrap Layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need help in making a form layout because of bootstrap's automatic line break for every form element. This is what I want to achieve:
[image]

and this is what i have done so far: 
[image]

I want to achieve that inline effect for the textbox and thumbnails with equal sized as the text + textbox input. I tried using bootstrap's input add-on but it doesn't seem to make the thumbnail and input box equal.
Here is the code of my second screenshot:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span>4:45</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Title">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div>
        <div>
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Files/Profile/7.jpg")" class="img-circle m-b" alt="logo" style="height: 50px; width: 50px">
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Description">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div>
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Files/Profile/7.jpg")" class="img-thumbnail m-b" alt="logo" style="height: 50px; width: 50px">
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Change Photo">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help how to achieve that layout I just need the thumbnail + input box alignment. Any help is appreciated. Thank you! Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Here is modified code to work proper. input-group-addon class is missing in your code.

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">4:45</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Title">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon ">
                    <img src="images/mission.jpg" class="img-thumbnail m-b" alt="logo">
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Description" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <img src="images/mission.jpg" class=" img-thumbnail m-b" alt="logo">
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Change Photo" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```